# WooCommerce get product variation attribute name and value from order items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, product-variations

I am making custom thank you page for my WooCommerce shop where I am able to display the Cart item's attribute and value correctly but in Thankyou page I failed to show that Can you please help me that ?

Working Code for mini cart item:

```
$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item => $values) {
    
    $cart_item = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $item ];
    $variations   = wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );
    if( $cart_item['data']->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
        $attributes = $cart_item['data']->get_attributes();
        $variation_names = array();
        if( $attributes ){
            foreach ( $attributes as $key => $value) {
                $variation_key =  end(explode('-', $key));
                $variation_names[] = ucfirst($variation_key) .' : '. $value;
            }
        }
        echo implode( '<br>', $variation_names );
        
    }
    
}
```

And the output like

```
Color : Red
Size  : 4mm
```

Same thing I like to show in thank you page So I re-coded it like order format and loop through it which is not working

```
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ($items as $item_key => $item) {
    $product = $item->get_product(); 
    if( $product->is_type( 'variation' )){
        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $variation_names = array();
        if( $attributes ){
            foreach ( $attributes as $key => $value) {
                $variation_key =  end(explode('_', $key));
                $variation_names[] = ucfirst($variation_key) .' : '. $value;
            }
        }
        echo implode( '<br>', $variation_names );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** *(handling custom attributes too)*

Use `$item->get_product()` to get the current `WC_Product` Object from order items using `get_attributes()` method on product variations, instead of `get_variation_attributes()` which is to be used only on the parent variable products.

```php
$order_items = $order->get_items();

foreach ($order_items as $item_key => $item) {
    $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product Object

    if( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        $data_array = array();

        if( $attributes ){
            foreach ( $attributes as $meta_key => $meta ) {
                $display_key   = wc_attribute_label( $meta_key, $product );
                $display_value = $product->get_attribute($meta_key);
                $data_array[]  = $display_key .' : '. $display_value;
            }
        }
        echo implode( '<br>', $data_array ) . '<br>';
    }
}
```

It should work now, for normal product attributes and custom ones too.

Comment: yes Thanks it working  `$attributes = $product->get_attributes();`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I know it's an old answer, but just curious. So there is no helper function is WC to get proper labels instead of manipulating the strings? I have two word attributes and it picks up only the last word from the attr name. Also, there are attributes added from the WP menu with `pa_` appended and there is some added from the product edit page itself. How to deal with the edge cases where we need both of these types listed with proper label and values? Thank you!

Comment: @RPMcMurphy I have made an update, just for you.